# Remove leading bytes from the file then write remaining bytes to otput

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, cut

I need to find the first substring in a (text)file, drop/cut leading bytes, write remaining bytes to a new file. I tried SED,AWK,CUT but got so lost in not so good results. Sounds a simple task to do. This should work in .sh cmdline script.

Input file may have newlines or everything is in a single line, so to find `<?xml` marker should work character or byte level. Leading bytes are random and any length.

Input file:
`something I want to drop<?xml............to the end of file</root>`

Output file: `<?xml............to the end of file</root>`

Comment: Is the prefix a known length?  That could be a job for `dd` with `iskip` option.

Comment: @TobySpeight prefix bytes not a known length, sometimes a keyword is the first chars in a file.  I have an accepted answer with sed magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed -n '/.*<?xml/,${s//<?xml/;p}' file`

From xml line to end line (`$`), strip leading, then print.

- `-n` doesn't print unless `p` tells it to print the pattern buffer.
- The empty `//` in the replacement will match the previous match string, in this case `/.*<?xml/`

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/.*?(?=<\?xml)//s' ip.txt
```

`-0777` will cause entire file to be read as single string. The `s` flag will allow `.` to match newline character. `(?=<\?xml)` will lookahead to match `<\xml` and thus all characters that occur before this string gets deleted.

To save the changes inplace, use `perl -0777 -i -pe`